# Can't get nginx to reply to ab with compressed content

Tags: nginx, http, http-headers, ab

```
ab -n 1 -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' http://mywebsite.com/
```

This always returns the uncompressed content (I can see that both from its size and because I'm sniffing the traffic with `ngrep`).

However, if I request the content with Firefox, the result is compressed. `Content-Encoding: gzip` it says. I've tried to specify with `ab` all request headers Firefox specifies, as I see them sniffed, but still `ab` gets it uncompressed and Firefox gets it compressed.

I'm running a version of nginx which I have compiled myself but is identical to the Debian squeeze backports 1.2.1 version, except that it has the syslog patch. ApacheBench 2.3 revision 655654. Here is the nginx gzip configuration:

```
gzip                on;
gzip_min_length     1000;
gzip_types          text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
gzip_disable        "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";
gzip_vary           on;
```

The document type is `text/html` (not listed above but always compressed by nginx; besides, I tried adding it, with no difference). It is dynamic, received from a `uwsgi` backend.

Sniffed request headers from `ab`:

```
GET [...] HTTP/1.0.
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate.
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8.
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686 on x86_64; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.1.
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5.
Cookie: csrftoken=[...].
Authorization: Basic [....].
Connection: keep-alive.
Host: [...].
```

Sniffed request headers from Firefox:

```
GET [...] HTTP/1.1.
Host: [...].
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686 on x86_64; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0.
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8.
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5.
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate.
Cookie: csrftoken=[...].
Authorization: Basic [...].
Connection: keep-alive.
```

Hmmm, maybe it could be the protocol version.

Comment: Try setting the header to `Accept-Encoding: compress, gzip`

Comment: No difference. Why should that make a difference anyway, given that Firefox says `Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate`?

Comment: Please specify the versions of Nginx and 'ab' involved. Also, please include all the `gzip_*` directives from Nginx that you are using.

Comment: Also, please show the incoming HTTP request headers, as generated by Firefox, and as generated by 'ab'.

Comment: @MarkStosberg I added that information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, the protocol version is the problem. As Mark Stosberg explains, whether HTTP 1.0 supports compression or not is not clear. What *is* clear is that, by default, nginx supports compression only for 1.1. This can be changed with a [configuration option](http://nginx.org/r/gzip_http_version):

```
 gzip_http_version 1.0;
```

Answer (score 1):

That appears that it could be an issue with `HTTP 1.0` vs `HTTP 1.1`. [Documentation about the differences](http://www8.org/w8-papers/5c-protocols/key/key.html) include this:

> HTTP/1.1 (unlike HTTP/1.0) carefully specifies the Accept-Encoding
>   header, used by a client to indicate what content-codings it can
>   handle, and which ones it prefers. One tricky issue is the need to
>   support ``robot'' clients that are attempting to create mirrors of the
>   origin server's resources; another problem is the need to interoperate
>   with HTTP/1.0 implementations, for which Accept-Encoding was poorly
>   specified.

Here's an idea for a cross-check Take Firefox and `ab` out of the equation and send raw HTTP requests using a purpose-built tool for that, like `GET` from the `libww-perl` distribution. Here's an example syntax to get started:

```
GET -sSe -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, default'  'http://example.com' | head -40
```

You can see how to add more headers to make it match your request from there.